# TS Type is missing the following properties

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I'm using Angular 7.x.x with TS in version 3.2.4.

I have two TS interfaces. One ist extending the other one:

This is the main interface:

```
export interface Result {
      var1: string;
      var2: number;
      var3: boolean;
}
```

The second one just adds a property:

```
export interface ResultPlus extends Result {
      var4: boolean;
}
```

Now I have a service returning `Observable<Result[]>.`

In my component I subscribe on this service:

```
dataArray: ResultPlus[] = [];    

getResults(): void {
      this.service.getResults()
          .subscribe(data => {
            **this.dataArray** = (data as unknown as ResultPlus);
          });
     }
```

(There are no * in the code)

Now the **this.dataArray** (bold above - **) is underlined in red and it says:

*error TS2740: Type 'ResultPlus' is missing the following properties from type 'ResultPlus[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.*

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing your cast to `ResultPlus[]` (the array type) not the single instance:

```
**this.dataArray** = (data as unknown as ResultPlus[]);
```

ie, you've declared dataArray to be an array of ResultPlus type.

If you're trying to add to `this.dataArray` for each item `data`, then you need to push to it - something like:

```
this.dataArray.push(data as unknown as ResultPlus);
```

Comment: my solution for similar case: `<any>data` or `data as any`